# Transferring Spreadsheet without formatting in Access

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am getting a Compile Error of Expected Expression when I use the below code to transfer a spreadsheet in access 2013 without formatting.  What am I doing wrong here?

'''    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet  ,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml,"TBL_Record_B",, True,  '''

Answer (score 0):

thanks I figured it out

'''DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "TBL_Record_B", "TBL_Record_B", True'''

But this does not allow the user to choose where to save the file.